# Ejecutar archivos de Resource sin escribirlos a disco

Tags: c#

como dice en el titulo, si yo tengo un executable en la carpeta Resources, puedo ejecutarlo sin necesidad de escribirlo a disco?

Comment: Da mas detalles, no se te entiende bien

Comment: En un proyecto de csharp, yo tengo un executable en la carpeta resources, para poder ejecutarlo , debo escribirlo a disco usando File.WriteAllBytes y luego ejecutarlo, hay alguna forma de ejecutarlo sin escribirlo a disco o integrarlo al propio codigo como hace Costura.Fody con las dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace tiempo también estuve buscando una respuesta a esto, pero no encontré algo especifico. Pero lo implemente de la siguiente manera:

1. UseShellExecute es para usar el shell de windows
2. WindowStyle es para ocultar la ventana de ejecución en caso de que se muestre la pantalla del cmd.

```
private static void ExecuteFile(ref string prmError)
{
    try
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"LAS2.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        prmError = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Y para esto hay que tener el archivo ejecutable ya sea .exe, .py, o lo que desees ejecutar, en la mismo dirección de tu principal proyecto de tu solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]